# Will our Beta label be removed?

Tags: discussion

Since we learned that [Matter Modeling is graduating](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/298/5) and [Quantum Computing is graduating](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/517/2293) and [Freelancing is graduating](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/340/25010) and [Retrocomputing is graduating](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1065/18437) and [Economics is graduating](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2161/20029), I'm curious if Community Building will be too?

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like we aren't there yet.  There are certain criteria that need to be met and as of yet Community Building doesn't meet those criteria.

Answer (score 2):

The criteria set forth in the MSE (December 16th 2021) announcement: "[Congratulations to the 59 sites that just left Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/282094)" is:

> "For the sites that are leaving Beta today, the following criteria were determined:
>
> - The site needed to be in public Beta for at least six months
> - The site needed to have at least 1000 open questions
> - At least 70% of the questions on the site needed to have at least one upvoted answer"
>   <sub>Currently [1689 questions out of 1803](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A1) = ~94%.</sub>

It is possible to remain in beta even if you are eligible to graduate:

> "Another process change was introduced today: For this group of eligible communities, we allowed the communities to stay in Beta if they didn’t feel ready to leave that state yet. A couple of sites indicated that they felt they wanted to focus on increasing engagement in their communities a bit, and didn’t feel like now was the right time to leave Beta.".

It is possible to leave beta even if you are not 100% eligible to graduate, by request (with an explanation of why there should be an exception, as was done for one other site):

> "In the past, moving a site out of Beta required a developer’s assistance to remove the Beta label and to either keep reputation levels lowered or bring them up to the regular levels ...

> Now, thanks to one of the amazing engineers on our Public Platform team (Adam Lear, take your bow), the CMs have a tool to allow us to do this without a developer. So in the future, if a site is eligible and ready to leave Beta, we can process those requests ad-hoc and in a more timely manner.".

Our [Area 51 Statistics](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52070/moderators) suggests that we need more questions per day and more visitors; but I do not know that is the nature of this community, it's a bit of a niche.